# NERDTree opens up everytime I hit return in Normal Mode

Tags: vim

This is getting really annoying for me. I only have this line for my NERDTree in my .vimrc file,

```
nmap <silent> <c-o> :NERDTreeToggle <CR>
```

Every time I hit return key in my Vim window in normal mode (Command Mode). NERDTree pops up.

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's generally what I use.

```
:noremap <Leader>n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

autocmd VimEnter * exe 'NERDTree' | wincmd l
```

starts up nerdtree on start and give me ',n' as my toggle

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when i mapped

> `<C-m>`

to NERDTree. Fixed it by changing to something else which didn't involve ctrl key